# Aeron ReplayMerge never merges

Tags: aeron

My `ReplayMerge` gets stuck in state `ATTEMPT_LIVE_JOIN`, then times out due to no progress. It adds the live destination with no issues (I see the corresponding subscription appear in aeron-stat and the `onImageAvailable` callback is invoked). <s>Eventually it catches up fully but doesn't transition to the next state.</s>

After an investigation, I found that the problematic check is in function `shouldStopAndRemoveReplay` where `image.activeTransportCount() >= 2` is false because `image.activeTransportCount()` stays at `1`. If it weren't for that check the `ReplayMerge` would succeed.

Here are my `ReplayMerge` parameters:

```
replayChannel = "aeron:udp"
replayDestination = "aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:0"
liveDestination = "aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:0|control=localhost:12345"
```

I've tried both the Java client and the C++ client. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** `aeron-stat` on the client side gives looks like this:

```
 42:                    1 - rcv-local-sockaddr: 41 <some IP address>:54709
 43:          452,985,472 - sub-pos: 24 -106708072 3000 aeron:udp?control-mode=manual @0
 44:          452,985,472 - rcv-hwm: 28 -106708072 3000 aeron:udp?control-mode=manual
 45:          452,985,472 - rcv-pos: 28 -106708072 3000 aeron:udp?control-mode=manual
 46:                    1 - rcv-local-sockaddr: 41 0.0.0.0:39238
 47:          452,971,520 - sub-pos: 24 -106708098 3000 aeron:udp?control-mode=manual @452971520
 48:          452,985,472 - rcv-hwm: 89 -106708098 3000 aeron:udp?control-mode=manual
 49:          452,971,520 - rcv-pos: 89 -106708098 3000 aeron:udp?control-mode=manual
```

The first driver subscription is from the `replayDestination`. All the numbers go up as you would expect, like a normal replay.

The second one is from the added `liveDestination`. Once created it doesn't catch up at all, contrary to my initial assessment above. `sub-pos` and `rcv-pos` are stuck at the initial position of 452971520, but the `rcv-hwm` goes up together with the position of the replay subscription. Doesn't this indicate that data is being received but not read on the live destination subscription?

I noticed that the `ReplayMerge#image` is simply defined as

```
image = subscription.imageBySessionId((int)replaySessionId);
```

So I tried to instead poll the `Subscription` I passed to the `ReplayMerge` constructor so that both images would get polled internally. That did not help.

Comment: Why are you adding `endpoint=localhost:0` on the liveDestination?

Comment: Hi @MartinThompson, thanks for your help with this. That's what ReplayMergeTest.java does (in aeron-system-tests). I tried many things out out of desperation. I get the same behavior whether I specify `endpoint=localhost:0`, `endpoint=localhost:9000` or no `endpoint` at all in the `liveDestination`. I have added diagnostic info to the question.

Comment: Nevermind, ReplayMergeTest has `LIVE_ENDPOINT = "localhost:23267"`

Comment: Without seeing a worked example it is difficult to tell what you are missing.

Comment: @MartinThompson agreed, I will come up with a simple example

Comment: @MartinThompson I have created [a simple test case](https://gist.github.com/jrsala-auguration/b595d5075fe98d85d7f3397c472870ac) that exhibits the problem. It runs an archiving Media Driver where a Publication gets recorded, and a normal Media Driver with a `ReplayMerge` that replays the recording and attempts to merge with the live feed. The `ReplayMerge` never succeeds despite clearly having caught up in terms of image position.

Comment: In your example I can see various issues with the URIs you have used. It is not one simple thing I can point at for you to fix and it would be best you got some training or a better understanding of Aeron channel configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue (encountered with [this code](https://gist.github.com/jrsala-auguration/b595d5075fe98d85d7f3397c472870ac)) by ensuring the `replayChannel` passed to the `ReplayMerge` is session ID-specific.

File ReplayMergeTest.java in the aeron codebase does it with

```java
private final String publicationChannel = new ChannelUriStringBuilder()
    // ...
    .tags("1," + PUBLICATION_TAG)
    // ...
    ;

private final String replayChannel = new ChannelUriStringBuilder()
    .media(CommonContext.UDP_MEDIA)
    .isSessionIdTagged(true)
    .sessionId(PUBLICATION_TAG)
    .build();
```

so that the session ID of the replay channel is set to be that of the `Publication` associated to tag `PUBLICATION_TAG`. This works as well in the case where the publishing media driver and subscribing media driver are distinct but you still have to somehow communicate the Publication tag to the subscriber which might be inconvenient.

So the solution I'll be going for is to take the session ID from the recording descriptor of the recording to be replayed, at the earlier point where I discover recordings with `AeronArchive#listRecordingsForUri` (or similar).

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/jrsala-auguration/34f6c73c8398c0e68b1a8e17828010ce) shows a working `ReplayMerge` across two media drivers.